# Kdenlive: MP4 file icon

Tags: kdenlive

I am using kdenlive to create mp4 files.

How do I indicate which image (or which point on the timeline) that will appear as the mp4 file icon when I display the mp4 file in Microsoft File Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i input.png -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -disposition:v:1 attached_pic output.mp4
```

- `-map 0` and `-map 1` will map all streams from both input files (numbered as `0` and `1`) into the output file,
- `-c copy` will directly copy all streams into the output file (i.e. without transcoding),
- `-disposition:v:1 attached_pic` will tag your picture (the **v**ideostream #**1**) as as the embedded cover / thumbnail.

Answer (score -1):

This question has been answered in a previous post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/597945/set-mp4-thumbnail).

The best way to do it is by using [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/).

If you save the frame of video you want as the thumbnail in .png format, you can use the following command to apply the thumbnail to your file in ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -i IMAGE.png -acodec copy -vcodec copy -map 0 -map 1:0 OUTPUT.mp4
```

Comment: Sorry, did not work. After running the ffmpeg command, the video appears as a large traffic cone (this is because I am using VLC media player as my default video viewing app). Any other suggestions?